# How to define list of items in groups in PERL

Tags: perl, shell, unix, scripting, makefile

I have a list of multiple variables and a perl script which operates on those variables.

The list is something like ::
group A :
var 1
var 2 
and so on

group B :
var 1 
var 2
and so on

My perl script operates on these variables depending on which group i want.

Is there a way that I can put all the groups (and the variables) in a single file using some perl-functionality so that all i need is to pass the group name to the script. The script will automatically pick the related variables of that group from the pre-defined list and operate on them ( something like we do using a makefile ).

Even a shell-script would be fine.

Comment: Post your script. what you  try?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you're looking for is called data marshaling, and like all things Perl, there's more than one way to do it. The three most commonly used methods of data serialization (the opposite of data marshaling -- writing data to a file in a way that preserves its structure) are YAML, Data::Dumper and JSON.

Data::Dumper writes the data out as native perl code: your examples above might look something like this:

```
$VAR1 = (
    { group1 => [ 'abc', 'def' ] },
    { group2 => [ 'red', 'blue' ] }
);
```

YAML and JSON are cousins... they use different text formats to represent arrays and hashes. YAML is typically used for configuration files, whereas JSON is emitted by javascript, and is more likely to be found in perl scripts that send and receive data on the web.

Data::Dumper is part of the Perl standard library. YAML and JSON libraries can be found on CPAN.

the output from Data::Dumper can be used directly as Perl code, and there are funtions in both the YAML and JSON libraries which will load data directly into Perl data structures.